# Icon in electron

Tags: electron, icons

I have a problem to change icon in Electron.
The code work fine, but when I add the line <<icon: "img/icon.png">> is produced a blank program (without anything).
This is the code:

function createWindow () {

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        devTools: false
    },
    icon: "img/icon.png"
});
win.setMenu(null);
win.loadFile('index.html');
win.webContents.openDevTools();
```

}

Comment: Any error output in the console you're trying to launch the application from? This could have a lot of reasons and thus without details, we can't help you. If you have more information, please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

To change icon of the window pass it in `BrowserWindow` constructor and use absolute path for simplification

> `icon` (NativeImage | String) (optional) - The window icon. On Windows it is recommended to use ICO icons to get best visual effects, you can also leave it undefined so the executable's icon will be used.

You will need to use some converter to generate `.ico` and `.icns` files.

```
let icon;
switch (process.platform) {
  case 'win32': icon = path.resolve(__dirname, 'img', 'icon.ico'); break;
  case 'darwin': icon = path.resolve(__dirname, 'img', 'icon.icns'); break;
  case 'linux': icon = path.resolve(__dirname, 'img', 'icon.png'); break;
}

const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        devTools: false
    },
    icon
});
```

Also, you can create `NativeImage` like this: `const icon = nativeImage.createFromPath(path.resolve(__dirname, 'img', 'icon.png'));`

But, you don't actually need to set icons manually, electron will use executable's icon by default. So just configure `electron-packager` to use proper icons (add `packagerConfig: { icon: img/icon } }` in `forge.config.js` and place `icon.png`, `icon.icns` and `icon.ico` into `img` dir)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I solved with the following command: electron-package --overwrite --icon=icon.ico.

Answer (score 0):

Right, but the problem is that doesn't exist anything of error.
But... I've just done another attempt with the following command: electron-package --overwrite --icon=icon.ico
Now works!!! but the question is: WHY ???